# How to A/B test two separate checkouts via GTM/GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, ab-testing

We have been developing a new checkout process and want to A/B it against our existing checkout process to see if it performs better over a specific time period. We are currently using the GTM Data Layer like so:

> ```
> [   {
> "ecommerce":     {
>   "checkout":       {
>     "actionField":         {
>       "step": 1,
>       "action": "checkout"
>     },
>     "products":         [
>       { etc...
> ```

And our GA Enhanced ecommerce looks like this:
[GA funnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i7Ia.png)

The new checkout is a one page checkout that has a different order of steps:

1. shipping address
2. shipping method
3. payment information
4. review

Can someone help with the best way to set up an A/B test in GTM/GA so that we can track both checkout flows and compare?

Thanks!

Comment: How will the A/B test be administered?

Comment: The thought is to set a cookie with a value for A and B customers to segment them to the target checkout. We do this often for other tests, but I've not set it up to A/B two different checkout streams before. Setting the cookie, and streaming the customers is the easy part, it's how to properly track via GTM and into GA funnel that we're wondering how do to.

Comment: This can be easily set up with a Google optimize experiment of type A/B testing. Create a Google optimize account, create a container and configure the container with your website

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you can use checkout option or a session-scoped custom dimension.

With checkout option you can have something like (note, I'm using gtag.js, but the idea should translate to GTM/DataLayer):

gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
  "checkout_step": 1,
  "checkout_option": "checkout variant",
  "value": "A"
});

The other thing you can do is define a custom dimension in GA, call it "variant" or "AB Test" and create a cookie variable in GTM to read the variant type and send that along with all your hits in a custom dimenion.